# im trying to run this code but for some reason it doesnt work can somebody help me?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
for i in df.Revenue:
  if df.Revenue.index(i) <= df.Revenue.mean():
    df.Revenue.index(i) = 0
  else:
    df.Revenue.index(i) = 1
print(df.Revenue)
```

and the syntax error is: can't assign to function call

Comment: What do you think `df.Revenue.index(i) = 0` is doing?

Comment: its just replace the value of the index with 0 isnt it?

Comment: No, that's not how Python works; you can't assign something to the result of a function call, like `foo(bar) = 1` - that's invalid. You _can_ assign a value to an index of an indexable object, like `foo_list[bar] = 1`.

Comment: Ok. thx man you helped alot

Comment: Apart from other issues, you seem to be trying to mutate `df.Revenue` in a loop, but in that case it would make `df.Revenue.mean()` a moving target (different in later iterations of the same loop). Also, a [mcve] would help clarify your question.

Comment: im trying to replace the column df.Revenue by checking every index and see if its taller than the average of the whole column, if it is i want it to be 0 otherwise i want it to be 1, thats the code i came up with but i know its completly wrong can you help me?

Comment: `df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].le(df['Revenue'].mean()).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

So, the function `df.Revenue.index(i)` gives you the index of an item in `df.Revenue`. Here's a similar example:

```
d = {"a": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], "b": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], "c": [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]}
df = pd.Series(d)
print(df.a.index(0.3)) # output: 2
```

The output of the above code is `2` because for the `a` item, the index of the value `0.3` is `2`, since the item at `a` is `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`.

So, in your case, if you want to replace a value in `df.Revenue` with a different value, you'd first get the index of the item via `idx = df.Revenue.index(value)`, then set it via `df.Revenue[idx] = newvalue`.

However based on the rest of your code, including the line `df.Revenue.index(i) <= df.Revenue.mean()`, I think you might just need to use `df.Revenue[i]`, and use the actual indices for values of `i` rather than the actual values in `Revenue`. This is because `df.Revenue.index(i)` returns an index, but you're comparing it to `df.Revenue.mean()`, which is a mean of the values of `Revenue`, so it doesn't really make sense to compare an index to a value.

So, your code might need to look like this, although without knowing its exact requirements I can't be sure:

```
for value, i in enumerate(df.Revenue):
  if value <= df.Revenue.mean():
    df.Revenue[i] = 0
  else:
    df.Revenue[i] = 1
print(df.Revenue)
```

Alternatively, without `enumerate`:

```
for i in range(len(df.Revenue)):
  if df.Revenue[i] <= df.Revenue.mean():
    df.Revenue[i] = 0
  else:
    df.Revenue[i] = 1
print(df.Revenue)
```

However I don't know the `pandas` library, so there's probably a much simpler way to do this, but I'm mainly trying to show code as similar to yours as possible except that actually does what you want.

Comment: thx man im doing this highschool project and this has been delayed me for a while

Comment: please don't use loops like this with pandas, don't used chained indexing to assign values, don't use dot-accessors to assign values, and don't mutate a series as you loop through it since under this approach `df["Revenue"].mean()` is constantly changing

Comment: `df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].le(df['Revenue'].mean()).astype(int)` does everything this loop-based approach does

Comment: @PaulH please feel free to update my answer with your suggested improvements, since like I said I don't know anything specific about the pandas module